# How do I fix missing @angular/Core modules?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

I can not run the Angular 2 project.

What I tried:
- running the project by using npm install and npm start | does not work
- I cloned quickstart from the github and replaced with my src folder and I still get the "can not find module in @angular/core"

Here is the full console output: https://www.dropbox.com/s/5plmqrjd6ge0lta/error.txt?dl=0

Comment: Try installing t manually using `npm install @angular/core`

Comment: happen to me too. i installed ngx-bootstrap with npm - and poof!!!  angular core was gone , i use angular 5.2

Answer (score 6):

Many people will come here. I have had the same problem. Do not panic. You are probaly following the tutorial of tutorialspoint.

Just install the core again using NPM

```
npm install @angular/core
```

Answer (score 0):

There [was/is a bug in certain versions of npm](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/17379) that causes installed modules to disappear when using `npm install someModule` ... or `npm install someModule --save-dev`

This was apparently an issue if the module being installed was from a GitHub repo and lacked a specific commit hash to reference for the installation. Although the issue was marked "closed" and the repo archived several months ago at v5.6.0, I ran into the problem today w/the latest `npm 6.4.0`

In my case, doing `npm install rxjs` completely removed the `@angular/core` module, along with my `@ionic-native` plugins, and anything else I'd installed individually (and then it failed to actually/properly install rxjs anyway!!)

Tip: copy your existing npm modules folder as a backup before starting updates or removing it entirely & trying to `npm install`.

You can manually install to your project via `npm install @angular/core`, but depending on the npm version (or the angle of the moon at that precise moment, who knows) be aware that you might wind up with other missing dependencies.

Also try `npm install @angular/core && npm install` ... Apparently the additional `npm install` helps replace the randomly deleted/missing modules in some cases.

Comment: I just had this issue when trying to install lodash...except it only ghosted several packages within @angular/core, but regardless, a bunch of files broke. At some point I switched to a different branch that didn't have these issues, then switched back, and now only one file is broken even though I didn't touch anything. Then I switched away and back again and everything was fine! ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯